# Need Regular Expression pattern for validating path directory structure in Flex?

Tags: regex, flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I need a regular expression pattern for validating the following path directory:

"C:/SomeDefaultPath/Input/swift/*.pdf"

and

"../Input/swift/*.pdf"

I've tried the regexp pattern got from net search, but I couldn't validate the above mentioned paths.

Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance,
Marshal.

Comment: I have solved this. The pattern: /^(?:[\w]\:|\..)(\/[a-zA-Z_\s0-9\-\/\.]+)+\*\.(swf|jpeg|png)$/ validates the given path directories. Actually I've made slight changes with the pattern and it worked. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new RegExp("^(([a-z]:)|\\.\\.)([\\\\/][^\\\\/:*?\"<>|\r\n]+)*[\\\\/]\\*\\.[a-z]*$", "im")
```

You can test it with the following simple application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Bindable]
        private var expString:String = "^(([a-z]:)|\\.\\.)([\\\\/][^\\\\/:*?\"<>|\r\n]+)*[\\\\/]\\*\\.[a-z]*$";
    ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <mx:RegExpValidator flags="im" expression="{expString}" source="{pathInput}" property="text" id="pathValidator" />
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:TextInput id="pathInput" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0" change="pathValidator.validate()" />
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I'd tried for the following path directory (it's not actual path, just for example) C:/MainDir/SubDir/SampleFile/*.png and it didn't validate it. Could you plese check this. If you want to check this online try this link: http://ryanswanson.com/regexp/#start. Many Thanks, Marshal.

Comment: Your path works fine with my regexp. I've added simple app to test my regexp.